# Syntax error when creating a CTE in mysql

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

**Problem:** [Challanges Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/challenges/problem?isFullScreen=true) on HackerRank using MySQL

I am trying to create a CTE t1 for this query

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT h.hacker_id, h.name, COUNT(c.challenge_id) as c_count FROM hackers h
INNER JOIN challenges c
ON c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
GROUP BY c.hacker_id, h.name
HAVING COUNT(c.challenge_id) NOT IN (SELECT b.c_count FROM
(SELECT c.hacker_id, COUNT(c.challenge_id) as c_count FROM hackers h
INNER JOIN challenges c
ON c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
GROUP BY c.hacker_id
HAVING c_count < (SELECT MAX(c_count) FROM (SELECT COUNT(c.challenge_Id) as c_count FROM hackers h
INNER JOIN challenges c
ON c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
GROUP BY c.hacker_id) as a)) as b
GROUP BY b.c_count 
HAVING COUNT(b.c_count) > 1))
SELECT * FROM t1
```

but I get syntax error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't1 AS (SELECT h.hacker_id, h.name, COUNT(c.challenge_id) as c_count FROM hackers' at line 1

I am sure there's nothing wrong with my query since it works just fine without a CTE but I need a CTE for conditional ordering required by the problem later on. also I did search online and I am sure this is the right syntax for a CTE in mysql.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return?

Comment: @BillKarwin 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Comment: Common table expression syntax is a new feature in MySQL 8.0. The earlier 5.x versions do not support this syntax. You must either upgrade to 8.0, or find another way to solve your problem.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks, did not expect hackerrank to use outdated version of mysql

Comment: Technically, MySQL 5.7 is a legitimate current version because its end-of-life is October 2023. But it's not the _latest_ version of MySQL.

Comment: @BillKarwin Do you suggest any good alternatives to CTEs to use?

Comment: In your example, you could just run the query inside the CTE. You aren't doing anything with the CTE besides `SELECT * FROM t1` so I don't know why you even made a CTE.

Comment: @BillKarwin No, I was just getting started. I had to self join the table. that's why I needed the CTE

Comment: Then you could define it as a view.

Comment: @BillKarwin Unfortunately, HackerRank does not allow you to create views. Guess I am stuck with the option to repeat my query.